# error on removing char from variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

please advise on what to change in syntax

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
                //click on nav
                $('#nav li a').click(function() {
                    //set variable
                    var targetDiv = $(this).attr('href');
                    var targetPic = $(this).attr('href');
                    //remove # from var
                    targetPic = str.replace('#', '');
                    //hide !=var
                    $('div').not( + targetDiv) .hide('puff', 1000);
                    $('div').not('.' + targetPic) .hide('puff', 1000);
                    //show =var
                    $('div' + targetDiv) .show('puff', 1000);
                    $('div.' + targetPic) .show('puff', 1000);
                    })

            });
```

Comment: could you please ask a question, not just code?

Comment: I apologize about the question part. I should have wrote: Is this the correct way to handle capturing the href attribute from an anchor, store it in a variable, modify the variable to exclude the # so that it can be used as a class selector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
targetPic = str.replace('#', '');
```

should be

```
targetPic = targetPic.replace('#', '');
```

[since there is no variable](http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-string-replace.php) `str` imho

[but this code **will not work**](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-attr-href-giving-full-path-instead-of-relative-in-ie) in browsers where `$(this).attr('href');`returns the full absolute url (thiat is including `http://......#`) like some versions of IE

Comment: Regarding your last comment about IE I'm not sure if it's right. jQuery will only return the content of the "href" attribute, which is only what the html contains, right?

Comment: I am not quite sure... we had some issues with that in jQuery 1.4 and IE6, but perhaps it is fixed.../ http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-attr-href-giving-full-path-instead-of-relative-in-ie

Comment: I will use another selector if the href does not return correctly in all browsers. Thank you for the heads up though. I am assuming since my anchors point to divs and not external links, it would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

To @Caspar Kleijne's answer I would also like to add that I see another mistake in your code :

```
$('div').not( + targetDiv) .hide('puff', 1000);
```

should probably be

```
$('div').not('#' + targetDiv) .hide('puff', 1000);
```

Comment: You correction was my initial code except that the variable returns #divname, so concatenating another # would result in ##divname.

Comment: @jquery101 well in that case, you should remove the `+` before `targetDiv`